# Extraer foto de perfil API login facebook con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook-api

Tengo este código de JavaScript y deseo extraer la foto del perfil de `facebook` para guardarlo en mi base de datos mysql. he intentado muchas cosas y no puedo.

```
function fb_login(){
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    FB.login(function(response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            //console.log(response); // dump complete info
            access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

            // window.location='user_profile.php';
            // FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            // user_email = response.email; //get user email
            // // you can store this data into your database             
            // });

            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                // console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                // document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                // 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
                var user_name = response.name;
                var user_link = response.link;
                var user_image= response.image;
                // var user_id = response.id;
                var user_email= response.email;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax-insert-fb-user.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
                    type: "post",
                    data: {access_token:access_token,user_name:user_name,user_link:user_link,user_image:user_image,user_username:user_id,user_email:user_email}, //The data your sending to some-page.php
                    success: function(){
                        window.location='<?=$header?>';
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        window.location='index.php?error';//login.php?error';
                    }   
                });
            });

            } else {
            // user hit cancel button
            // console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            $('#messagefb').modal();

        }
        }, {
        scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ami me funciono de esta manera si tienes alguna duda puedes escribirme (Y)

```js
// creo el construtor
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://web.facebook.com/luiis.ramosgutierrez";
function llamar(){
//solicito el la estructura del html mediante la variable url.
http.open("GET",url,true);
http.send();
http.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(http.status==200 && http.readyState==4){
       imagen(http.responseText) // le envio mediante el parametro.
        }
}
function imagen(urlimagen){
    let imagenes = urlimagen; // busco el url de la imagen.
    var num = imagenes.indexOf("_11kf");
    var num1= imagenes.substring(num);
    var texto = num1.indexOf(">");
    let http = num1.indexOf("src=")
    var texto1 = num1.substring(http+5,texto-3);
     imaginar(texto1);
}
    function imaginar(texto1){ 
     let palabra = texto1.replace(/amp;/gi,"");  
    $('#caja2').text(palabra);
    $('#imagen1').attr('src',palabra);
  }
}
llamar();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// creo el construtor
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://web.facebook.com/luiis.ramosgutierrez";
function llamar(){
//solicito el la estructura del html mediante la variable url.
http.open("GET",url,true);
http.send();
http.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(http.status==200 && http.readyState==4){
       imagen(http.responseText) // le envio mediante el parametro.
        }
}
function imagen(urlimagen){
    let imagenes = urlimagen; // busco el url de la imagen.
    var num = imagenes.indexOf("_11kf");
    var num1= imagenes.substring(num);
    var texto = num1.indexOf(">");
    let http = num1.indexOf("src=")
    var texto1 = num1.substring(http+5,texto-3);
     imaginar(texto1);
}
    function imaginar(texto1){ 
     let palabra = texto1.replace(/amp;/gi,"");  
    $('#caja2').text(palabra);
    $('#imagen1').attr('src',palabra);
  }
}
llamar();
```

Comment: Por favor agregue una descripción de cómo este código fuente resuelve el problema del usuario que realizó la pregunta.

Comment: @Flavio Edú Mataqque podrías especificar más el código? no me funciona :C