# Traer IMAGEN DE PERFIL de Facebook usando JAVASCRIPT desde PERFIL URL

Tags: javascript, html, imagen, input, facebook

Buen día. Estoy intentando traer la **Foto de Perfil** de un usuario mediante su **Link de Perfil** el cual es solicitado en un Input.
Intenté usando [Este Código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/241019/213559), pero no hubo respuesta alguna y parece ser que el código dado por el usuario no es efectivo según comentarios. Me pueden ayudar a encontrar una forma que funcione? sólo con una guía a seguir me basta :D Gracias.

```
<div> <span>Enlace de tu Perfil de Facebook:</span> <input id="FB" type="url"></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto no responde del todo tu pregunta pero podrías iniciar con este código, sabiendo que dentro de cualquier perfil de facebook puedes ejecutar JS para obtener el url de la imagen de perfil:

```
//creas una variable que contiene todos las etiquetas g de la pagina de facebook
const gElements = document.getElementsByTagName('g')
//ahora guardas el url de la imagen de perfil en una variable e imprimes
const urlImagen = gElements[0].firstChild.href.animVal
console.log(urlImagen)
```

Puedes probar ese fragmento de codigo en la consola del navegador en cualquier perfil de facebook y veras que te da un enlace a su imagen de perfil, luego ya puedes usar un request para obtener el html de el perfil y con el codigo de arriba sacas el url de la imagen...

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirve.

Comment: disculpa las molestias. Sabes de algún post en donde pueda ver más a profundidad cómo hacer tal cosa? o podrías ayudarme? no estoy muy adentrado a JS :/